# Python - Scatter mode error for plotly library

Tags: python

I'm using VS Code with Jupyter notebook extension. The function call below is generating an error

```
def _generate_traces(name_df_color_data):
traces = []

for name, df, color in name_df_color_data:
    traces.append(go.Scatter(
        name=name,
        x=df.index,
        y=df,
        mode='lines',
        line={'color': color}))
return traces
```

---

ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'mode' property of scatter
        Received value: 'line'

```
The 'mode' property is a flaglist and may be specified
as a string containing:
  - Any combination of ['lines', 'markers', 'text'] joined with '+' characters
    (e.g. 'lines+markers')
    OR exactly one of ['none'] (e.g. 'none')
```

https://python-forum.io/Thread-plotly-graph-objs-Scatter-mode-error
this link has the entire traceback-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Line 9: I changed it from 'line' to 'lines'
2. compiled project_helper.py
3. closed workspace in VS Studio
4. Exited VS Studio
5. Reopened VS Studio
6. Voila !!

2, 3 and 4 were the key steps!!